# Why ubuntu does not recognize Tex version 2015

Tags: command-line, latex

I downloaded and installed Tex Live 2015. Under `/usr/local/texlive/2015`. I updated also my path as follows:

```
PATH="/usr/local/texlive/2015/bin/x68_64-linux:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games"
```

However when I run `tex --version` the following is displayed:

```
TeX 3.1415926 (TeX Live 2013/Debian)
```

How i can make it read my new installation?

This is some debug info:

```
$ kpsewhich plain.tex
/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/plain/base/plain.tex

$ echo $PATH
/usr/local/texlive/2015/bin/x68_64-linux:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games
```

`which tex` does not list anything.

Comment: How did you update the `PATH`? If you edited `.profile`, etc., did you re-login or source the changes?

Comment: What do you mean how i updated? I edited the .bashrc file. I did not do anything with any .profile file. Should i create any?and put what?

Comment: Ok, after editing `.bashrc`, did you open a new terminal, or run `. .bashrc` or `source .bashrc`?

Comment: See also http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1092/how-to-install-vanilla-texlive-on-debian-or-ubuntu and https://github.com/scottkosty/install-tl-ubuntu

Comment: I opened a new terminal and nothing happend

Comment: I have done all these from the relative question but nothing changed

Comment: My cat/environment is set up correctly also to `PATH="/usr/local/texlive/2015/bin/x68_64-linux:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games"`

Comment: echo $PATH
`/usr/local/texlive/2015/bin/x68_64-linux:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games`

Comment: Add the result of  `which tex`, `kpsewhich plain.tex` to your question, please.

Comment: your result of `kpsewhich plain.tex` shows that your `tex` installation still points to the old one. Are you sure you have installed the new TeXLive in `/usr/local` and not in another place? What do you see if you do a `ls /usr/local/texlive/2015/bin/x68_64-linux`? (and please, add `which tex` also to the question). Read also all of http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/95373/38080, maybe there is some good hint there.

Comment: ls /usr/local/texlive/2015/bin/x86_64-linux/ lists the full dir with the executables

Comment: Why kpsewhich shows the old one?how i can change that?