# Installation of TexLive 2021 problems

Tags: texlive

Well I am afraid that it is duplicate question but I have searched over 8 posts and haven't succeeded. I tried to install in Ubuntu 18.04 TexLive 2021/TL2021 (I am using texstudio). I had previously unsuccessfully downloaded TL2021 but continued using TL2017. I did exactly the following steps:

In terminal

```
sudo apt autoremove --purge texlive tex-common
 rm -rf /usr/local/texlive/2021
rm -rf ~/.texlive2021
 rm -rf ~/.texlive2017
```

Deleted manually from the file's manager any files relative to TL2017 (I don't remember the exact names, but they were like `texlive2017`)

Downloaded the tar.gz file from the [TUG site](https://tug.org/texlive/acquire-netinstall.html) and (tried) to follow the instuctions.

Changed directory (from terminal) where the unzipped install-tl perl file was.

Executed `perl install-tl` (didn't work), so I executed `sudo perl install-tl` (maybe it was an unsafe choice)

Entered code and -i option.
(After 2 hours approximately that the packages were downloaded and because I thought they were commands)

```
PATH=/usr/local/texlive/2021/bin/x86_64-linux
 MANPATH=/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/doc/man
INFOPATH=/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/doc/info
```

(didn't give output)
Found the `.profile` file and while it was

```
# ~/.profile: executed by the command interpreter for login shells.
# This file is not read by bash(1), if ~/.bash_profile or ~/.bash_login
# exists.
# see /usr/share/doc/bash/examples/startup-files for examples.
# the files are located in the bash-doc package.

# the default umask is set in /etc/profile; for setting the umask
# for ssh logins, install and configure the libpam-umask package.
#umask 022

# if running bash
if [ -n "$BASH_VERSION" ]; then
    # include .bashrc if it exists
    if [ -f "$HOME/.bashrc" ]; then
    . "$HOME/.bashrc"
    fi
fi

# set PATH so it includes user's private bin if it exists
if [ -d "$HOME/bin" ] ; then
    PATH= PATH="$HOME/bin:$PATH"
fi

# set PATH so it includes user's private bin if it exists
if [ -d "$HOME/.local/bin" ] ; then
    PATH="$HOME/.local/bin:$PATH"

fi
```

I changed it to

```
# ~/.profile: executed by the command interpreter for login shells.
# This file is not read by bash(1), if ~/.bash_profile or ~/.bash_login
# exists.
# see /usr/share/doc/bash/examples/startup-files for examples.
# the files are located in the bash-doc package.

# the default umask is set in /etc/profile; for setting the umask
# for ssh logins, install and configure the libpam-umask package.
#umask 022

# if running bash
if [ -n "$BASH_VERSION" ]; then
    # include .bashrc if it exists
    if [ -f "$HOME/.bashrc" ]; then
    . "$HOME/.bashrc"
    fi
fi

# set PATH so it includes user's private bin if it exists
if [ -d "$HOME/bin" ] ; then
    PATH="/usr/local/texlive/2021/bin/x86_64-linux:$PATH; export PATH"
INFOPATH="$INFOPATH=/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/doc/info; export INFOPATH"
MANPATH="$MANPATH=/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/doc/man; export MANPATH"
fi
#OLD ONE
#    PATH="$HOME/bin:$PATH"

#PATH=/usr/local/texlive/2021/bin/x86_64-linux:$PATH; export PATH
#INFOPATH=$INFOPATH=/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/doc/info; export INFOPATH
#MANPATH=$MANPATH=/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/doc/man; export MANPATH
# set PATH so it includes user's private bin if it exists
if [ -d "$HOME/.local/bin" ] ; then
    PATH="/usr/local/texlive/2021/bin/x86_64-linux:$PATH"
INFOPATH="$INFOPATH=/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/doc/info; export INFOPATH"
MANPATH="$MANPATH=/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/doc/man; export MANPATH"
fi
#OLD ONE
#    PATH="$HOME/.local/bin:$PATH"
```

Maybe it is wrong. I don't know.
From searching on this posts
[1](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/171715/how-do-i-tell-texmaker-where-to-look-for-packages),[2](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/564730/texlive-2020-installation-ubuntu),[3](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/456243/what-is-the-easiest-way-to-set-path-of-updatednew-version-texlive-installation),[4](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/554212/how-do-i-finish-installing-tex-live-on-ubuntu),[5](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1092/how-to-install-vanilla-texlive-on-debian-or-ubuntu),[6](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/379878/set-path-to-use-the-current-tex-live-bin-directory),[7](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1092/how-to-install-vanilla-texlive-on-debian-or-ubuntu),[8](https://askubuntu.com/questions/713956/why-ubuntu-does-not-recognize-tex-version-2015),[9](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/266969/texlive-update-how-do-i-permanently-set-the-path),[10](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/379878/set-path-to-use-the-current-tex-live-bin-directory), I tried the following

```
which tex
export PATH=/usr/local/texlive/2021/bin/x86_64-linux:$PATH
export INFOPATH=$INFOPATH=/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/doc/info
export MANPATH=$MANPATH=/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/doc/man
echo $PATH
 whereis pdftex
```

None of them gave a result. So I am a little bit confused. What did I do wrong or what didn't I do? Texstudio can't compile any tex file now.

Comment: You're using Ubuntu 18.04?  Is there any reason why you can't (1) use the texlive version that goes with Ubuntu 18.04 or (2) upgrade your version of Ubuntu to a later version?  Either option will mean you don't need to install Texlive from source, which quite frankly, can be quite complicated.

Comment: I won't upgrade Ubuntu soon, because at the moment I have exams. I had also [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/630361/names-of-the-files-using-subfiles-package?noredirect=1#comment1572100_630361) problem. Before I was told that the installation of TL2021 won't work, I tried to install it. I will probably go back to TL2017, but maybe it is good to know for next time. I will definetely need it.

Comment: Do you consider using DockerTex from https://github.com/raabf/dockertex ? Who forced you to use TL2021?

Comment: @N0rbert Well if it is safe and find somewhere how to install it I will think about it.

Comment: @N0rbert Nobody forced me, but now I have a problem. Myself, I don't know that many things about tex or ubuntu, so I thought that the previous problem I had could get solved with an upgrade.

Comment: Installing from source is safe, but if you "don't know many things about tex or ubuntu", then I would suggest you stick to the package that comes with your version of Ubuntu.  I like to say I know some things about tex and Ubuntu, but I still wouldn't venture into installing from source unless I absolutely have to (and I rarely do).

Comment: Ok, but is it enough to execute `sudo apt-get install texlive-full` or I have to do more than that? I completely deleted everything relative to TL2017@Ray

Comment: Ok. I removed everything from older version using [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/95502/248968) answer and then executed `sudo apt-get install texlive-full`. This installed TL2017, not TL2021 for anyone who may wonder in the future.

Comment: I routinely install vanilla texlive under Ubuntu, to be uptodate with TeX. The easiest way seems to be: remove any tex related packages of Ubuntu, download the texlive installation script, and install it systemwide (with root privileges), below `/usr/local`. The binaries will be linked into `/usr/local/bin`, which should be on the command path anyway, so you are done. Otherwise you may add the PATH extensions of your post *at the end* of `.bashrc`, `.profile` etc, depending on the shell you are using. See section "Integrating vanilla tex live with debian' at https://tug.org/texlive/debian.html

Comment: If you do `echo $PATH`, then you should see the directory containing the texlive binaries in the list, either `/usr/local/bin` or `/usr/local/texlive/2021/bin/x86_64-linux`. Then, `which tex` should give the fully qualified path to the binary.

Comment: @gernot I have seen in posts that there is a risk when I install TL with root privileges.

Comment: @ΝικολέταΣεβαστού Which one, except that you have to trust the people packaging TeXLive, like with every other package that you install?

Comment: @gernot well I have seen [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/187379/248968).

Comment: @ΝικολέταΣεβαστού The author of the other post is basically right. If you add a separate user for texlive that owns /usr/local/texlive, and install texlive as this user, then this is the best solution.